# Add multiple dynamic leaflet maps with Vue3

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3, ref

I'm trying to add multiple leaflet maps dynamically in my Nuxt Vue 3 app.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in listitems">
 <div id="map" :ref="dynamicmap[index]"></div>
</div>
```

and then in onMounted:

```
for(n=0; n<countitems; n++)
{
map2[n] = L.map(dynamicmap[n]);
}
```

How I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot!
Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encapsulate a/one map as a separate Vue component?

```js
<div v-for="(item, index) in listitems">
 <MyLeafletMap :key="index"/>
</div>
```

MyLeafletMap.vue then consists only of

```
<div id="map" :ref="dynamicmap"></div>
```